# NavigationController doesn't rotate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I have two views, both under the NavigationController.
I **don't** want View 1 (on the left) to rotate, but I **do** want the View 2 (on the right) to rotate. View 1 and View 2 are routed to different classes.
[image]

I put this code in the View 2 class to implement the behavior and it's not working. It works with modal views in my app, thought

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

I wouldn't like to make the view №1 rotatable under any circumstances.
Any ideas how to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you're wanting is unfriendly to the user and possible against HIG. The reason it isn't working is because there are protections in UINavigationController against this disruptive behavior. When you have viewControllers Nav, tab, or modal with different rules for rotation it can sometimes fail, jerk, or otherwise not work at all as you see.

Basically I'm saying don't do this. Not that its not possible.

Comment: Would you then recommend to implement the rotating behavior for the 1st view to make it look more natural?

Comment: Yes. If you're going to support rotations, which I suggest, Then you should probably support the same rotations throughout the entire app. I know it can be more work but your users will appreciate it.